# better exposed filters and bootstrap 3. Problems with alignment

Tags: bootstrapping, views

I have Drupal 7 and the BEF to filter a view. My site is running the Drupal Bootstrap framework V3. The regular 'basic' theming for the exposed filters works, but I would like to use checkboxes and the JQuery slider.

I have a problem with the formatting on check-boxes and sliders.[image]

I've googled it, but didn't find anything relevant.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome. We cannot write missing themes for you. Either report incompatibility in module and theme issue queues, or start fixing it yourself, and ask when you will hit specific problem.

Comment: Bit harsh! This forum is for Drupal questions and this is clearly a Drupal question. If all questions that ultimately relate to coding issues, there would be no questions! This little module: https://github.com/rogercodina/bef_bootstrap_fix mentioned in https://www.drupal.org/node/2121203#comment-9588835 works a treat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/node/2121203 gives some answers...

> Look at bootstrap/theme/process.inc at function
>   _bootstrap_process_input and comment out or remove the 'select' in there.

Still looking for the "ultimate solution" myself as well.

Comment: Great little module to fix this: https://github.com/rogercodina/bef_bootstrap_fix